# Group theory exercise.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

1. Show that every group G with identity e such that $x ∗ x = e$ for all
   $x ∈ G$, is abelian.
2. If $G$ is a finite group of even order, then there exists $a ∈ G$ such that $a\neq e$
   and $a^2 = e$.

**My attempt.**
For the first point, since $ x * x = e $, it can be followed that $ x = x ^ {- 1} $. Then, for $ a, b \in G $ we have that $ (ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = ba $. And that shows that $ G $ is abelian.

For the second point. Let $ G $ be the given group and for each $ g \in G $ let us consider the set $ \{g, g ^ {- 1} \} $. This set has two elements if $ g \neq g ^ {- 1} $ and a single element (per repetition) if $ g = g - 1 $. So, $$ | G | = 2 | \{\{g, g ^ {- 1} \} \mid g \neq g ^ {- 1} \} | + | \{g \in G \mid g = g ^ {- 1} \} |. $$ Since $ | G | $ is even and the first addend of the second member is also, the cardinal of $ \{g \in G \mid g = g ^ {- 1} \} $ must be even. Then, since the neutral $ e \in \{g \in G \mid g = g ^ {- 1} \} $, then there must exist a $ g \in G $ with $ g \neq e $ such that $ g = g^{-1} $, this is $ g ^ 2 = e $, which ends the test.

Comment: Yep, these arguments work. Note that (b) generalizes a bit, if $S$ is a finite set and there is an involution $f$ on $S$ (that is a function $f: S \to S$ with $f \circ f$ equal to the identity) having exactly one fixed point (i.e. only one $x$ for which $f(x)=x$), then $|S|$ must be odd. Same proof as yours with $f$ in place of inversion.

Comment: Your attempt is right. Note after the phrase :per repetition" you have a typo. [now it says $g=g-1$ but you want $g=g^{-1}$ ... in raising $x$ to the $-1$ power the $-1$ need to be enclosed in braces.]

Comment: Thank you both very much for taking the time to review my attempt. I had not noticed the error in the latex code that I had there in my argument, but he could still get the idea that was the important thing :).